# Populate 2nd dropdown based on 1st dropdown selected in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using PHP and Postgresql/PostGIS data base. My database schema is something like this.

1. **divname**       |   **distname**
2. dhaka         |  Manikganj
3. dhaka         |  Narayanganj
4. dhaka         |  Munshiganj
5. Khulna        |  Jessore
6. Khulna        |  Kushtia
7. Khulna        |  Meherpur

I am using the following codes

```
<?php
$con = pg_connect("Connection Parameter");
if (!$con)
  {
  die("Could not connect: " . pg_last_error());
  }
$divquery = "SELECT DISTINCT divname FROM union_bgd 
        ORDER  BY divname";
$distquery = "SELECT DISTINCT distname FROM union_bgd
        ORDER  BY distname";
$resultDiv = pg_query($con, $divquery); 
$resultDist = pg_query($con, $distquery);

    ?>
    Division
  <select id="division" name="division" onclick = "">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select a Division</option>
  <?php
      while($dd1 = pg_fetch_array( $resultDiv )) 
        {

        echo '<option value= "' . $dd1['divname'] . '">' . $dd1['divname'] . '</option>';

        }

    ?>

</select></br>
District
<select id="district" name="district" onclick = "">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select a District</option>
  <?php
      while($dd2 = pg_fetch_array( $resultDist )) 
        {

        echo '<option value= "' . $dd2['distname'] . '">' . $dd2['distname'] . '</option>';

        }

    ?>

</select>

 <?php   
pg_close($con);
?>
```

Currently its populating all the divname and distname in the dropdown but I want if the "Dhaka" is selected only the distname under the dhaka will show in the second dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use AJAX to do this, since when PHP forms the page it doesn't know which option is selected in the first dropdown... If you have access to jQuery it can be done [quite simply](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained)

Comment: I saw this but I am new at developing. specially I dont know jQuery. If a specific help it would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

There should be `where` clause in

```
$distquery = "SELECT DISTINCT distname FROM union_bgd ORDER  BY distname";
```

Edit like this,

```
$distquery = "SELECT DISTINCT distname FROM union_bgd where divname=".$selected_dist." ORDER  BY distname";
```